# Should I say "He don't" or "He won't send him on deliveries"?

Tags: difference

What is the difference between these two sentence and also grammatically which sentence is correct,

1. He don't send him on deliveries.
2. He won't send him on deliveries.

Comment: Please be more precise and specific with the context. The sentence could mean a lot of things.

Comment: 1) He *doesn't* send him on deliveries.

Answer (score 1):

"He don't..." is incorrect because you need to say "doesn't" in the third person indicative singular.

"He won't..." is good English.

Please note that the two sentences do not mean the same thing.

- The first ("He doesn't...") means that one man does not have the habit of sending another man on deliveries.
- The second ("He won't...") means either (1) in the future the first man will not send the second man on deliveries, or (2) the first man habitually refuses to send the second man on deliveries.